# Google search result shows upvote number instead of the post title

Tags: bug, search

I found Google search result sometimes shows the upvote number of the stackoverflow post, not its title. The image below shows "86" appearing instead of its actual [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901523/whats-a-faster-operation-re-match-search-or-str-find) title "What's a faster operation, re.match/search or str.find?" when I searched "python regex vs substring". It turns out that the number 86 is the upvote number of the post.

It rarely happens so I've just ignored it. But just wondering why this happens.

[image]

Comment: That's a bug on Google side. Meta Stack Exchange is for reporting bugs in Stack Exchange itself. As for why, we can't know, only Google developers responsible for this feature might know. (Also not sure.)