# Wrong metadata in Google search result

Tags: bug, google, seo

It is the first time I see a [Stack Overflow answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63438874/i-have-an-error-cannot-find-module-utils) metadata so wrong on Google Search ([mine](https://www.google.com/search?q=wp-scripts+cannot+find+module+utils) or a [direct link to the question](https://www.google.com/search?q=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F63438874)).

I'm not sure where else to file a bug related to [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization). If this isn't the right place, feel free to close / delete this post and I'll file this wherever it belongs!

[image: Screenshot of a faulty Google search]

Comment: [This has happened before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389375/165455).

Comment: @AaronBertrand That other report was closed as off-topic for being beyond SE's control. However, is this really the case? I think it's somewhat within SE's control because they supply Structured Data to Google which they're supposed to use, and something may be going wrong with that.

Comment: @Sonic It feels to me like something going wrong in the process on their end. If we did something to alter the metadata or break the contract, it would happen for _all_ questions on _every_ site, not just onesy-twosies?

Comment: @Sonic in my view, the bug is on Google side and their responsibility to fix, however SE might have something they can do to help, thus not voting to close this time. This should ideally be joint effort of Google and SE to fix it.

Comment: From https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/title-link#issues "*Why the title link in search results might differ from the page's <title> element or main heading: If we've detected an issue on the page, we may try to generate an improved title link from anchors, on-page text, or other sources.*". It's not obvious to me which "common issue" listed on that page applies in this case, though. So I suspect it's on Google to fix the issue.